# MH-Z19 calibration. What to do for a non-permanently powered device?

Tags: arduino, gas-sensor

I have 2 [MH-Z19](https://www.winsen-sensor.com/d/files/infrared-gas-sensor/mh-z19b-co2-ver1_0.pdf) for measuring indoor CO<sub>2</sub> calibration. One is running permanently on a Raspberry Pi, the other one on an Arduino Pro Micro on a handheld device that is turned on only when I want to measure.

The specs say that the MH-Z19 is auto-calibrating every 24 hours. That feature can be turned off and it can be calibrated by sending a zero-point calibration command.

Does this zero-point calibration (400 ppm) survive powering off the MH-Z19 on the Arduino?

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you?

Comment: I don't see a comment about persistent or nonpermanent storage of the calibration.

Comment: That's it then you'll have to contact the supplier or, allow other folk to check the data sheet.

Comment: I added a link to the data sheet

Comment: Really you need to ask the manufacturer.  But you could try calibrating it, powering it off for a couple of minutes and then back on.  Take readings and see how they compare to  before.  Then force another calibration and see if the readings change.  Do the same after several days powered off...

Comment: "NOTE：ZERO POINT is 400PPM, PLS MAKE SURE THE SENSOR HAD BEEN WORKED UNDER 400PPM FOR OVER 20MINUTES"

Comment: I can't help but ask what you are going to measure. I'm wondering if maybe you intend to explore Global Warming? If so, this is way inadequate. Not precise enough. Specs state 3% + 50ppm possible error [3%=~12ppm; ie 52ppm total error] 'climate.gov' states measured CO2 increase rate has been averaging 0.6 ± 0.1 ppm per year. (86years just to register any readable change on this sensor setup!}. It would be affected by many things, city concentrations, wind, local businesses, traffic, time of day, etc. BUT, could be a super learning exercise to explore local variations and sources!

Comment: Please advise me if the above comment is appropriate here. It is not related to answering the specific question. I couldn't help being concerned of many readers, and the OP, being disappointed if that is their goal. I understand these questions can remain a long time. I am a new SE participant, and don't know how all the features or responses work. Should I ask this in a chat somewhere? Please let me know if this is inappropriate, or if I should delete the above comment (and this one of course can get deleted either way).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the answer, but I know how you can find out!

Assuming you're not going to get any useful answer from the supplier; I have some good suggestions on how to test it; basically what Chris Stratton stated above.

Use a test gas, one that will throw the reading significantly high or low, then it will be easily apparent if it changes (looses calibration) when powered down.
[Before following my ideas, I am concerned if it could be a chemical based sensor that get consumed and used up over years of exposure, that a 100% exposure could ruin the sensor]. I found this link, maybe it is the same type of optical sensor descrtibed: https://www.azosensors.com/article.aspx?ArticleID=234
If your sensor is the optical type, then I think it would be safe from 0% to 100% concentration, without harm.
Also some gas mixtures may alter the actual CO2% reading, but doesn't matter for my test.

First - calibrate it in a overly rich *or* a low concentration of CO2 (your choice...)
Here are some easy test gases you probably have at home:

For a rich mixture or 100%: use CO2 - baking soda and vinegar, or alka-seltzer tablets, fire extinguisher (not my first choice), CO2 for a MIG welder.

For 0% CO2: use inert gas - Nitrogen and/or Argon used for welding, Halogen (aka Freon) keyboard dusters are halogen (no CO2, pure gas), Nitrogen is at tire shops too.

Get a jar or container or ziplock bag, as appropriate.
Put the sensor (or whole thing) in the container, fill with gas (purge or flush room air out with your choice of gas).
Now, observe that it is ready and has responded by reading really high or low now.
Do this with power on continually so far.
It should only take a few minutes, if you wait too long, it might 'self calibrate' on you.

Once it looks stable, do the calibration method you wish to test.
Do your calibration (power has not yet been interrupted, and still in the container).
Verify that it now reads close to 400ppm (the thing assumes you are calibrating it in 'normal' open air, and is adjusting itself accordingly, to read what it 'thinks' it should be showing).
It is now deliberately calibrated wrong, with an 'off-set'.
Now, power still on, once it has settled, take it out of the container; it should now go WAY off what you would normally expect to see.
Let it settle (by settle, I mean just wait until it stops, in each step above, if the reading is climbing or falling).
Now it should be a stable reading that is way high or low (depending on the test gas you chose).

NOW turn the power off, and wait however long you choose. (To see if, and how long, it 'keeps' a calibration with power off).

Turn it back on, and see if retained the same way-off reading, or reverted back to 'normal' readings of roughly 400ppm.
If it stays on the weird reading that we artificially induced, then that calibration was stored in memory.

You could try again with the other gas mixture, but I don't see any advantage to testing both ways; it just might be something interesting to do!

PS; you *did* intend to read CO2, and NOT CO, correct?
This tester is for Carbon Dioxide, not Carbon Monoxide (just checking).
My first instinct was that you just typed it wrong, but then I don't know what you are intending to do...

Comment: PS, it would be like if you had a electronic bathroom scale, and you 'zeroed' it with your hand on it. When you take your had off, it now reads wrong. Turn it off and back on again, and see if it goes back to '0', or stays 'wrong'...

Comment: If your trying to measure day-to-day variations, or long term changes, then don't forget to turn the 'auto-calibrated' feature off... I think you said as much...

Answer (score 1):

The zero point calibration will change over time as the sensor ages and temperature varies. So storing it isn't all that useful.

The way it works is to monitor over a 24 hour period, and assume that the lowest reading it sees is 400 ppm. That's because 400 ppm is the natural CO2 level of air at ground level.

For that calibration to be valid, the sensor needs to be in a well ventilated area. Outside is ideal, or indoors but in a room that isn't occupied for long enough for CO2 levels to return to baseline. How long that is depends on how well ventilated the room is. The datasheet recommends turning it on for indoor use, but that will depend how often the room is occupied. For example, in a hospital where people spend all day and all night in bed, emitting CO2, it probably wouldn't work very well.

You might try placing it outdoors periodically for calibration, and then bringing it back in with auto calibration disabled.

Comment: Meanwhile (2021) the natural CO2 concentration is about 420 ppm de to emissions

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the original question but shows a bypass solution.
I use a USB power supply to have the Arduino and hence the MH-Z19 permanently powered. Before I use it for mobile measurement I turn on the battery pack (it is isolated from the USB via a Schottky-Diode). I see a good match with my other permanently power MH-Z19 running on a Raspberry.